# Angular has deprecated the declaration of ng-app without name

Tags: angularjs

Consider the piece of code below:

part of html file:

```
<body ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">{{name}}</div>
</body>
```

part of js file:

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = "John";
}
```

I always put my controllers in some module, whose name I define in ng-app. How it works when I don't define any module ?

I just started with angular js and faced the above scenerio.

Comment: I'm not clear what your question is.  This syntax cannot be used in 1.3x or higher angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your app in the DOM with a name:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Next, register your app as a module in your JavaScript:

```
angular.module("myApp", []);
```

Note the array as the 2nd argument; this means you're registering a new module, rather than accessing a previously defined module.

Finally, register your controller(s) onto your app:

```
angular.module("myApp")
.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  // controller code goes here
}]);
```

Note the lack of the 2nd argument this time, as you're getting the previously defined `myApp` module.

Your question is answered in the [2nd step of the Angular tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02). If you're new to Angular, I suggest you start here (at [step_00](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00)).